# Linux Build Package - Configure Script Throws Error, But it's Wrong

Tags: linux, dependencies, package, configure, suse

**Server:** SLES v11 sp3
**Kernel:** 3.0.101-0.47.71-default
**Arch:** x86_64

So I am trying to build a src package and when I run the **"./configure"** script it's throwing some errors that required packages are missing. Since it's x86_64 I thought adding *"--libdir=/usr/lib64"* or *"--libdir=/lib64"* would help it find the packages it's looking for but I get the same error either way.

**The configure Script is failing with this error:**

```
..........
...SNIP...
..........
checking for xgettext... (cached) /usr/bin/xgettext
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for GEDIT... configure: error: Package requirements (
    glib-2.0 >= 2.13.0
    gio-2.0 >= 2.16.0
    gtk+-2.0 >= 2.13.0
    gconf-2.0 >= 1.1.11
    gtksourceview-2.0 >= 2.5.1
    gedit-2.20 >= 2.25.4
) were not met:

No package 'glib-2.0' found
No package 'gio-2.0' found
No package 'gtk+-2.0' found
No package 'gconf-2.0' found
No package 'gtksourceview-2.0' found
No package 'gedit-2.20' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables GEDIT_CFLAGS
and GEDIT_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

I checked to make sure I actually have these packages and it seems as though I do. So I'm not sure if it's just not finding them or what... And it also seems as though I have versions of those packages **>=** what they are asking for, so I'm kinda stumped...

**My Installed packages are:**

```
# rpm -qa | grep -i glib-2
libglib-2_0-0-2.22.5-0.8.14.1

# rpm -qa | grep -i 'gtk2'
gtk2-32bit-2.18.9-0.35.1
gtk2-2.18.9-0.35.1
gtk2-engines-2.16.1-4.26
gtk2-branding-SLES-for-VMware-11.1-0.5.99
gtk2-engines-32bit-2.16.1-4.26
gtk2-themes-0.1-737.22
gtk2-lang-2.18.9-0.35.1
gtk2-theme-SLES-for-VMware-11.1-0.7.95

# rpm -qa | grep -i 'gio'
libgio-2_0-0-32bit-2.22.5-0.8.14.1
libgio-2_0-0-2.22.5-0.8.14.1

# rpm -qa | grep -i 'gconf2'
gconf2-2.28.0-1.8.1
gconf2-lang-2.28.0-1.8.1

# rpm -qa | grep -i 'gtksource'
gtksourceview-lang-2.8.2-0.1.195
libgtksourceview-2_0-0-2.8.2-0.1.195
python-gtksourceview-2.4.0-1.32

# rpm -qa | grep -i 'gedit'
gedit-2.28.3-0.8.1
gedit-lang-2.28.3-0.8.1
```

Anyone have any ideas what the issue could be here? I'm not sure what else to try..?

I had also tried installing the RPM based package but get similar errors for missing packages. See RPM Installation error below...

```
warning: gedit-plugins-2.28.0-2.el6.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 signature: NOKEY, key ID c105b9de
error: Failed dependencies:
    GConf2 is needed by gedit-plugins-2.28.0-2.el6.x86_64
    pygobject2 is needed by gedit-plugins-2.28.0-2.el6.x86_64
    pygtk2 is needed by gedit-plugins-2.28.0-2.el6.x86_64
    pygtksourceview is needed by gedit-plugins-2.28.0-2.el6.x86_64
    rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by gedit-plugins-2.28.0-2.el6.x86_64
```

If anyone has ANY thoughts or suggestions please feel free to reply, it would be much very appreciated!

Thanks in Advance,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I was unable to resolve those errors directly with compiling... However, we have another server with the same OS and everything that already had that package installed *(which added more to my confusion why it wasn't working)* so to just give it a try I copied that server's directory **"/usr/lib64/gedit-2/plugins"** to the one I was working on and now everything seems to be working just fine. All the plugins were able to be activated and they seem to work.!

The contents of the directory that I copied over were:

```
/usr/lib64/gedit-2/plugins # ll
total 700
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   4096 Apr 28  2015 advancedfind
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    216 Apr 28  2015 advancedfind.gedit-plugin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   9856 Nov 13  2012 changecase.gedit-plugin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   6970 Apr 17  2014 codecomment.gedit-plugin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   9563 Mar 18  2014 codecomment.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8850 Apr 16  2014 codecomment.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8745 Mar 18  2014 codecomment.pyo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  18084 Nov 13  2012 docinfo.gedit-plugin
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Jul  2  2013 externaltools
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   9243 Nov 13  2012 externaltools.gedit-plugin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8579 Nov 13  2012 filebrowser.gedit-plugin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    179 Apr 17  2014 gpdefs.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    317 Apr 17  2014 gpdefs.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    315 Apr 17  2014 gpdefs.pyo
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   9654 Nov 13  2012 indent.gedit-plugin
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  18936 Nov 13  2012 libchangecase.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  19032 Nov 13  2012 libdocinfo.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 170256 Nov 13  2012 libfilebrowser.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  14816 Nov 13  2012 libindent.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  27320 Nov 13  2012 libmodelines.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  23248 Nov 13  2012 libsort.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  82168 Nov 13  2012 libspell.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  36104 Nov 13  2012 libtaglist.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  35840 Nov 13  2012 libtime.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   9177 Nov 13  2012 modelines.gedit-plugin
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Jul  2  2013 pythonconsole
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8602 Nov 13  2012 pythonconsole.gedit-plugin
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Jul  2  2013 quickopen
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   5719 Nov 13  2012 quickopen.gedit-plugin
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Mar 20  2015 sessionsaver
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   6035 Mar 20  2015 sessionsaver.gedit-plugin
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Jul  2  2013 snippets
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8805 Nov 13  2012 snippets.gedit-plugin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   9235 Nov 13  2012 sort.gedit-plugin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   9416 Nov 13  2012 spell.gedit-plugin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  16794 Nov 13  2012 taglist.gedit-plugin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  11861 Nov 13  2012 time.gedit-plugin
```

And since all these plugins seem to be working without any issuse I guess the configure script was wrong about the missing requirements as I had thought...

Thanks anyways....!